# Trusting a 3rd party CA in istio egress gateway (one way TLS)

Tags: istio, ca, istio-sidecar

Trying to access an external server from within a mesh.
That server has it's own certificate from a 3rd party CA, but can only do 1-way TLS.
I need the egress gateway to check against that CA key (not a public CA).

istio is configured to translate an HTTP request from the mesh to an HTTPS towards that server.

With this:

```
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: external-acme
spec:
  host: acme.default.svc.cluster.local
  workloadSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE 
 ...
```

The external server's certificate is never checked (any cert is accepted, connection succeeds).

Adding this to the TLS section:

```
      credentialName: acme
```

and adding a secret name "acme" with the 3rd part CA public key fails the connection, with the error

```
connection failure, transport failure reason: TLS error: Secret is not supplied by SDS]
```

How can I force CA key checking and where should I place that CA key?
Does the secret name matter?
What about the key name (such as in " --from-file=<<key>>=ca-root.cer").
Does it matter?